# django registration template

Tags: django, passwords, registration

I have made two templates(change passwd, change passwd done).
And, I tried to changepassword. then, Password changed.
But, Success page is not shown.only password_change page reloaded.
I dont know What is problems?

One more, I don't know where is registration folder.
Cloud you help it?
Thank you.

```
url(r'^accounts/chpasswd/?', 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_change', {'template_name':'password_change.html'}),
url(r'^accounts/chpasswd/done/?', 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_change_done', {'template_name':'password_change_done.html'}),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're changing password, you're using a function, that's most probably in your application's views.py file. When that function is at the end, it's most probably going to return some data, and it most often returns it to the template.

Here's an example:

```
return render_to_response('myapplication/frontend.html', {'profile': profile_obj},
        context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

In this case, it's going to return the value of variable `profile_obj` to the template `frontend.html`, which is probably in `/myproject/myapp/templates/myapp/frontpage.html`. After that, you can access that object's instances by invoking `{{ profile.instance }}` from within your template file.

More about this function [can be found here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#render-to-response).

Now, `urls.py` file is the file that's used for forwarding requests to desired application.
Example:

```
url(r'^accounts/chpasswd/?',
    'django.contrib.auth.views.password_change',
    {'template_name':'password_change.html'}), 
url(r'^accounts/chpasswd/done/?', 
    'django.contrib.auth.views.password_change', 
    {'template_name':'password_change_done.html'}),
```

And this means following(given your website is at www.mysite.com):

When a one opens `www.mysite.com/accounts/chpasswd/`, run function `password_change` from a view of `django.contrib.auth` module, and if that function is fruitful(returns a value of some kind), let it return a value to a template called `password_change.html`

django.contrib.auth module is used for stuff like that: logging in and out, password functions and so.

Now, you should be aware of 2 things:

1) your templates must be in a place where django will be looking for them, so check `TEMPLATE_DIRS` setting in settings.py.

2) I believe(but am not 100% sure) that Django already has such a template, predefined. In case you have the same template name as one of Django's default templates, make sure that your app comes before `django.contrib.admin` in `INSTALLED_APPS`, or else you'll be shown a django template(shares the same design as django admin).

===================================

## EDIT since question was edited, too

Try changing order in urls.py, like so:

```
url(r'^accounts/chpasswd/done/?', 
    'django.contrib.auth.views.password_change_done', 
    {'template_name':'password_change_done.html'}),

url(r'^accounts/chpasswd/?', 
    'django.contrib.auth.views.password_change', 
    {'template_name':'password_change.html'}),
```

Comment: 1. My templates is in TEMPLATE_DIRS. 2. it's my INSTALLED_APPS     'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.humanize',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'chart_tools',
    'medics.sbox',
    'registration',

Comment: first. I try to change password at accounts/chpasswd/. then change URL to accounts/chpasswd/done/. URL has changed. But, Web page has not changed. Only accounts/chpasswd/ page reloaded. Actualy password change successful.

Comment: in INSTALLED_APPS, put the `'registration'` to be the first in the list. After that, open your `/mydjangoproject/registration/templates/registration/password_change_done.html`

Comment: /mydjangoproject/registration/templates/registration/password_change_done.html is registration path? I tried it. but, A problem still consists . where is registration path?

Comment: @user1161599, when I wrote `/mydjangoproject/` I meant the path to your django project, the one with settings.py file.

Comment: password_change.html and password_change_done.html is in registration path. and, password_change.html page show done. so, I'm not thinking registration path's problems. what do you think?