# django : do not redirect password_change after password change olny password_change_form reloaded

Tags: django, redirect, passwords

password_change.html and htmlpassword_change_done.html are in registration folder.
and, i'm using to django.contrib.auth.views.password_change and django.contrib.auth.views.password_change_done.

I can access password_change page. but, It does not redirection password_change after password change olny  password_change_form reloaded.

so, I tried to access password_change_done page directly. also, password_change_form page is shown
I can not found root cause.

Comment: Let me get this straight: You're changing your password but it keeps refreshing the page instead of redirecting you to the success page? Have you overridden the templates? Perhaps you are hiding the errors like "passwords don't match" or "incorrect password". I looked at the view, and it would redirect you if the form was valid. Even if you don't supply a redirect, it would redirect to a non existent URL. Unless you passed it `post_change_redirect=''` : )

Comment: I tried to password_change(password_change_form reloaded). and try to re-rogin. then changed password successful. If passwords don't match then can show the error message. password_change_doen template is good.

Comment: possible duplicate of [django registration template](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8997923/django-registration-template)

Comment: Please do not ask the same question more than once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I already answered in [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8997923/django-registration-template):

Change the order in urls.py like so:

```
url(r'^accounts/chpasswd/done/?', 
    'django.contrib.auth.views.password_change_done', 
    {'template_name':'password_change_done.html'}),

url(r'^accounts/chpasswd/?', 
    'django.contrib.auth.views.password_change', 
    {'template_name':'password_change.html'}),
```

SIDE NOTE: Also, for the sake of all active StackOverflow users, if you get a solution that works, please mark the answer as accepted, so that people don't spend time answering if answer is not needed anymore.